# Is there a battery optimization app that allows me to turn or sync/data for all apps with an exception for certain ones?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-9, battery-saver

I'm guessing there is a 3rd party app that does this, but I'm not sure. Is there a way to turn off auto sync for all apps with an exception for certain ones? For example, when I snowboard, my phone dies super quick from the cold + apps trying to sync and find service. I would just turn my data off or turn on battery super saver mode, but I use a music app, Bluetooth for my headphones, a ski tracker + GPS, and resort maps. Is it possible to turn everything else off?
I have a Galaxy S9

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: The solution is: don't ask for an app, ask for "how to do it". This does not close out answers suggesting a specific app, but also not any other solutions (like not very well-known system settings). You can also ask for a specific app on the softwarerecs SE, as Andrew suggested. You can even create these questions simultanously (until they are essentially different, i.e. there you ask for an app, here you ask for a solution).